# How can I update an index object array by id

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have the object array's ID and I want to update the info with information I already have on my backend.

My code deletes every array and creates a new one with the new info.

I want to access the array with the variable ID and then change it's values:

```
const ProdcutSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    productDescription:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    pricePerUnit:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    productAmmount:{
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },

    /*productImagePath:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    }*/

});


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,

    },

    email:{
        type: String,

    },

    password:{
        type: String,

    },

    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },

    products:[ProdcutSchema]
});


//Update products
router.put('/dashboard/:id', (req, res)=>{
    const ID = req.params.id;
    const {product_name, price_PerUnit, product_Description, product_Ammount} = req.body;           //Get access to ajax data using body parser

    if(!product_name || !price_PerUnit || !product_Description || !product_Ammount){
        res.send('Please fill out all fields with valid content');
    }else{
        User.products.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id : ID },                          
            { $set: { products: {
                name :product_name,
                productDescription : product_Description,
                pricePerUnit : price_PerUnit,
                productAmmount : product_Ammount
            }  } },
            (err) => {
                 if (err) throw console.log('found errors');
                    console.log('no errors');

        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ObjectId of that item you want to update, code should look like this:

```
User.products.findOneAndUpdate(
{ _id: ID, "products._id": <here goes id for an array element> },
{
    $set: {
    "products.$": {
        name: product_name,
        productDescription: product_Description,
        pricePerUnit: price_PerUnit,
        productAmmount: product_Ammount
    }
    }
},
err => {
    if (err) throw console.log("found errors");
    console.log("no errors");
}
);
```

Also u gotta be aware that u need to supply an specific ID of an array element for this kind of situation when you want to update subdocument.

Comment: If i user User.products.findOneAndUpdate() it returns an error: Cannot read property 'findOneAndUpdate' of undefined. Even though products insdide Users is defined

Comment: Its not about products, its about your schema which is not properly imported or exported. After defining it, if you do it in separate file(which is highly suggested beacuse of modularity and reusabilty) you need to export mongoose.model() function with some parameters, it should be like this: module.exports = mongoose.model(name of model(it should be User, with capital U), variable for schema, name of collection you want to store this document in, of course you provide it in string)

Comment: I export it like this const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User; it worked for get post and delete why not put?

Comment: and if I get the id from the database, it won't update too. idk what is happening but its pissing me off

Comment: I suggest you to use post instead of put, since you can do updates with post, no need to necessary complicate http requests. Personally, when i build REST services i use GET and POST only